# IE8 doesn't zoom content when applying a CSS zoom value to a DIV

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, zooming

When I apply a zoom value to a DIV (via CSS 'zoom' property), IE8 doesn't apply tyhe zoom level to DIV's content (Chrome does).

Is there a workaround?

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/exicel/

code: http://jsbin.com/exicel/edit/

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example page? (Without any further information, my only suggestion is to apply the zoom to the immediate children of the div, i.e. `#your-div > * { ms-zoom: 2; }`.)

Comment: To be clear, 'zoom' is NOT a standard CSS property and only available on IE that I'm aware of. Surprised if it does work on Chrome. I know it doesn't work on Opera or Firefox. You can, and should, perform the same thing using proper CSS3 with transitions.

Comment: Thanks, can you post some links about these features?

Comment: try [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) or [this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-zoom) (combined with rotation)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No, I'm forcing users to switch to Firefox or Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 will not work even IE9 also

These Browser will work Perfectly

```
Internet Explorer 10
Mozilla Firefox
Google Chrome
Opera x
Safari (-webkit-)
```

Comment: IE8 applies zoom except it won't resize the dimensions of children element (except for its font-size). I guess it's because it's absolutely positioned and thus removed from the flow? EDIT: yes, removing this positioning will make zoom work for dimensions of children too. Not sure if it's a bug in this case...